# Delphi Prism XE

Tags: delphi, qt

На сайте embarcadero в описании Delphi Prism XE есть такая вот строчка:

Build cross-platform Mono applications and deploy on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X

Кто-нибудь пробовал делать приложения под Linux или Mac OS X на Prism-е?

Comment: Мне тоже любопытно. Есть тут кто такой? И как успехи?

Comment: Я бы не поставил на переносимость полученного приложения. Как бы там ни было, переносимость .NET приложений очень ограничена и Mono в конечном итоге просто баловство. По крайней мере пока (и это длится уже довольно давно).

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен... Microsoft'у желательно что бы разработка велась под Windows, а не "какие-то" там *.nix'ы...

Comment: Но всетаки Embarcadero не Microsoft и тем более есть же Delphi Prism XE  для macOS.
Просто стою перед выбором для кросс платформ и незнаю за что взяться
Delphi Prism XE , lazarius или QT или вообше чтото другое.

Comment: Из перечисленного вами самое нормальное - Qt.

Comment: А чтото луше Qt есть?

Comment: Был Kylix. Он был честно кроссплатформенный. Но он загнулся. Теперь вижу спасение только в Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую присмотреться к **DelphiXE2** там есть поддержка и **Win** и **Mac**, Lunix к сожалению (или к счастью ) нету.